# How to query live data depending on an argument with Android Room?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am working on an Android application where users can save meals and their amounts according to a specific date.
Time is stored as a `yyyy-mm-dd` string in a SQLite Database at the moment (I probably will change the data type later on).
The user can select the date on a `CalendarView` and the `RecylerView` should just show the meals on the selected date. I don't want to retrieve all the rows but just query the rows depending on the date.
I am using the [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

How can I achieve this?

I am using a `LiveData<List<MYOBJECT>>` and the appropriated Observable Listener:

```
final MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class); 
String myDate = getDateFromCalendarView();    

myViewModel.getMealsOnDate(myDate).observe(this, new Observer<List<MYOBJECT>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MYOBJECT> myObjects) {
            adapter.setItems(myObjects); // adapter from RecyclerView
        }
    });
```

This is the query in my DAO interface:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM meals WHERE meals_date = :date")
LiveData<List<MYOBJECT>> getMealsOnDate(String date);
```

At the moment the Observer does not react on a different value in `myDate` therefore I can not query different rows from my database.

Is this even possible or do I have to stick with query the whole table and then select the data from my `List<MYOBJECT`?

Comment: show me your DAO

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making the **list** `observable` make the **myDate** variable `observable`. Because its the date that is changing and not the list.
You can achieve this by:

Make your `myDate` as a `MutabeLiveData` in viewModel. Then you can change its value when date is selected from `CalenderView` using `setValue(newDate)`.

Now, observer this `myDate`, and on value change, fetch the list with update date value and update the `RecyclerView`.

Also use **TimeStamp** instead of storing date as `yyyy-mm-dd` String.

***********UPDATE*************

**Example for further clarification**

In `ViewModel` class do this

```
MutableLiveData<String>() myDate=new MutableLiveData<String>();
```

In `Activity` do this:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener( new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
   myViewModel.myDate.setValue(""+year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth);//This will invoke the observer
}});

myViewModel.myDate.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String newDate) {
           //do this on dedicated thread
           List<MYOBJECT> myObjects=myViewModel.getMealsOnDate(newDate)
           adapter.setItems(myObjects); // adapter from RecyclerView
        }
    });
```

**Note**: 
1.The `getMealsOnDate()` need not to be wrapped as LiveData. The method in `Dao` can return `List<MYOBJECT>` instead of `LiveData<List<MYOBJECT>>`.So you will need not to observe it.

2.Don't run the db queries on main thread, and do call the `notifyDataSetChanged` in `setItems()` of adapter to refresh the Recyclerview.

Comment: That sounds like a promising idea. Unfortunately, I still can't quite imagine how I can implement this in my ViewModel. Could you give me a small example?

Comment: Thank you for the good example! This would mean, however, that the RecyclerView will not be updated if there is a change (e.g. a new entry). That's why I use LiveData for my list of Meals. I don't have to worry about updating with an observer.

Besides, the database queries are only executed on the main thread for test purposes. I had a few problems with asynchronous execution

Answer (score 2):

Similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669526/7680523), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58303183/7680523) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49864121/7680523). I am sure you'll find appropriate samples you can modify for your use cases in the links provided above.

I would do it this way:
 in the viewmodel I'll have a mutableLive data variable holding myDate

```
MutableLiveData<String>() myDate = MutableLiveData<String>();
```

then I have a variable for mealsOnDate

```
LiveData<List<MyObject>> mealsOnDate = Transformations.switchMap(myDate, (dateString -> getMealsOnDate(dateString)))
```

then you can observe the mealsOnDate on the activity or fragments like this

```
viewmodel.mealsOnDate.observe(this, new Observer<List<MyObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<MyObject> list) {
            adapter.setItems(list)
        }
    });
```