# how to change LiveData observable query parameter with room database in android?

Tags: android, observable, android-room, android-livedata

I am using live data with room database and my activity observes live data provided from room database.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM BUS WHERE BUS_CATEGORY = :busCategory")
LiveData<List<Bus>> getLiveBuses( String busCategory);
```

ViewModels gets LiveData via Dao(Data Access Object) and activity observes this live data.

Now it works fine. But when busCategory changes i can't modify this live data to get buses for newly selected busCategory.

**So how can i observe this same liveData where query parameters is changeable?**

Comment: when changing your `busCategory` you need to call that `viewmodel` method again, to fetch new data with new `busCategory`.

Comment: @MuhammadAwais then it observes for both bus category, in onChanged method it also gets value for previous busCategory

Comment: For the second method you don't need to call `observe` method. As it is already observing in your view.
Once the data is changed your `onChanged()` method will be called with new data.

Comment: I have the same problem. Need to change the query param. After days of tests and searches, I did not come with a clear answer. Hope someone will illuminate us.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suggest you to to use viewModel. I did the query and observe changes using MutableLiveData.
First step

```
val mutableBusCategory: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
```

Setter for mutablelivedata

```
fun searchByCategory(param: String) {
    mutableBusCategory.value = param
}
```

observable to observe the change

```
val busObservable: LiveData<Bus> = Transformations.switchMap(mutableBusCategory) { param->
    repository.getLiveBuses(param)
}
```

and final step to observe the live data

```
 busObservable.observe(this, Observer {
        //your logic for list})
```

and to trigger mutablelivedata

```
searchByCategory(//categoryName)
```

Comment: I have more than 1 param. How can I use this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a reasonable expectation. It would make more sense to fire off a new query and subscribe to that.

Comment: i can remove observer and set new observer and call for new livedata. But how to stop current live data instance ? so that room will not emit data for current livedata instance.

Comment: Assuming you only want one response you can unsubscribe to it after getting that response?